# Axis ticks missing when setting Plot2DPanel in logarithmic scale

Tags: java

I'm currently using Plot2DPanel (jMathPlot) to plot a simple XY Series. I need that the X-axis to be logarithmic but, when setting that, the grid and ticks of the X-axis dissapears... any help?

```
public class Graficas2D {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] x = {125, 250, 500, 1000};
    double[] y = {.2, .34, .67, .5};

    Plot2DPanel grafico = new Plot2DPanel("SOUTH");
    grafico.addLinePlot("Test", x, y);
    grafico.setAxisScale(0, "LOG");


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mi grafico");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setContentPane(grafico);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```